# Two ways a TCP client can access a port in the client machine?

Tags: networking, tcp

Apparently there are two ways a client can access a port in the client machine. I've only found one so far.

The question:

When a client wishes to send a message to a server using TCP, it must establish a connection to a specific port and IP address. It must use a socket and a port on the client side to transport the data. Discuss the **two ways** that a client might get access to a port in the client machine.

I've read wikipedia and some other sites, and it looks like there is only one way TCP connects to a port? Am I not understanding this question?

Comment: You'd better ask for clarification from whoever gave you that question. Guessing what the question mean is generally not in scope of SO.

Comment: Note that the question asks about getting a port on the **client**, not on the **server**.

Comment: And note that it says 'access', not 'connect'.

Comment: Without more context, there's no way to know what two ways the questioner had in mind. I can think of dozens of possible answers where the "two ways" are completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of network communication on TCP/IP protocol from a client to a server (or another client)

1. TCP protocol
2. UDP protocol

The main difference between those 2 are; TCP protocol works the way just like you described: The client should try to open a connection on a specific port to an IP address and the remote side should accept the connection properly in order to start sending and recieveing the data through the socket. But the UDP protocol does not need to open (establish) a connection from point to point. It allows you yo send any data at any time without any condition other than a valid IP address and port number.

Note that when talking about UDP protocol, unlike the TCP, you will have no guarantee that your data (actually called "packet") has been successfully sent or not to the remote address at all. You will never know that. And it's only recommended for small amount of data packages. The bigger the packet means the less change of proper transmission.

Comment: Closest thing to what I think my instructor wants. Gracias.

Comment: @user106857 I doubt it. UDP wasn't mentioned in the question. It's about 'access to a port in the client machine', not about any of this.

Answer (score 1):

***Three*** 'ways a client might get access to a port in the client machine':

1. Specify a specific port and use the `bind()` system call.
2. Specify port zero and call `bind().` The system will allocate a client port.
3. Don't call `bind()` at all. The system will again allocate a client port on `connect().`

Don't ask me which two your instructor wants, or whether he wants something else completely, but that's how I would answer the question. Unless there is more to it than this, it is very poorly posed indeed.